# Test Each Row Group Value

Tags: reporting-services, visibility

SSDT 2012 building a report using a matrix.  I have a dataset that has a list of tasks for a given job.  The jobs are the rows and the tasks are the column groups.  In the dataset, a job will have 10+ rows, but because of the column groups, there is only one row and a column for each task.  Each task has either a completion date or the text values "Scheduled" or "In Progress".  I need to be able to eliminate rows where ALL of the tasks have a date (or in other words, NONE of the tasks have the value "Scheduled" or "In Progress".

I have tried about a hundred different nested IIF's and it appears as if they are only testing the FIRST row for a given job in the dataset.  How do I test ALL rows for a given job?

Comment: Can you show a small example of the table layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write something like into row visibility

```
=iif(isnothing(fields!Date.Value),true,false)
```